# How include multiple criteria in COUNT ROWS with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the next HTML code:

```
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Nº</th>
    <th>NOMBRE</th>
    <th>AREA</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="curso">

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Jose</td>
        <td>Gramática</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Luis</td>
        <td>Gramática</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Andrea</td>
        <td>Gramática</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Andrea</td>
        <td>Idiomas</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<p id="Cantidad"></p>

</body>
```

This code can count the number of rows using a criteria in the AREA field:

```
<script>

function ContarFila() {

var cantidadFilas = document.getElementById("curso").rows.length;
 
  let resultados = {};
  let elementos = document.querySelectorAll(
    "table tbody tr > td:nth-child(3)"
  );

  elementos.forEach(elemento => {
    if (resultados.hasOwnProperty(elemento.innerText)) {
      resultados[elemento.innerText]++;
    } else {
      resultados[elemento.innerText] = 1;
    }
  });

  console.log(resultados);
  for (let indice in resultados) {
    document.getElementById("Cantidad").innerHTML =
      resultados['Gramática'];
  };
}

window.onload=ContarFila();

</script>
```

When loading the page and using the 'Gramática' criteria of the 'AREA' field, the result is 3.

How do I include MULTIPLE CRITERIA with the 'NOMBRE' and 'AREA' field  at the same time?

Example:

Using Criteria 1: 'Grammar'

Using Criteria 2: 'Luis'

RESULT: 1

THAK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then perhaps this example below can help you:

```js
function getResult(table, search = {}) {
  const tableHeadCells = Array.from(table.tHead.rows[0].cells);
  const tableBodyRows = Array.from(table.tBodies[0].rows);
  const indexes = tableHeadCells.map((el) => el.dataset["label"]); // <= // ['index', 'nombre', 'area']

  const count = tableBodyRows.reduce((acc, row) => {
    isSearched = indexes.every(
      (key, i) => !search[key] || search[key] === row.cells[i].innerText
    );
    return isSearched ? ++acc : acc;
  }, 0);

  return count;
}

const table = document.querySelector('table');
console.log('1 => ', getResult(table, {
  area: 'Gramática'
}));
console.log('2 => ', getResult(table, {
  nombre: 'Luis',
  area: 'Gramática'
}));
console.log('3 => ', getResult(table, {
  index: '3',
  nombre: 'Andrea'
}));
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-label="index">Nº</th>
      <th data-label="nombre">NOMBRE</th>
      <th data-label="area">AREA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="curso">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Jose</td>
      <td>Gramática</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Luis</td>
      <td>Gramática</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Andrea</td>
      <td>Gramática</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Andrea</td>
      <td>Idiomas</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that in the header of the table, the columns are indicated by [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) `data-label` in order to understand which column belongs to which keyword. And then, we just count the number of elements in the loop, which completely match the specified requirements for all columns